# LIbGDX How to translate all text when language changed?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a game with LibGdx. I have multiple languages in my app which in properties file. When i change my language in the menu text is not translating, so i need to reboot my app to apply translation. I think it is because i load my propereties file once on a boot and than it is not changing. I can use setText() method in the buttonListener to change all buttons text, but i have too many buttons. So are there any ways to transtlate my app immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I believe setText() is the only way to get buttons to update their text. I don't know how you are storing the text in the different languages for your program, but as a general idea you could try creating a custom class which extends TextButton and inside have a reference to where you store the different language text. Then have a method like changeLanguage() which then gets the text for correct language and calls setText() on itself.

Then you could have an array which holds references to all of the buttons in your program and when you change the language use a loop to go through this button array calling changeLanguage() on each button to set all of your buttons to the correct language. This will be done very quickly and you won't have to manually call setText() on each button in your program.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to write an updateTextButtonsMethod() where i update text of my buttons according to the new language.